# Google+ stream write using C# and Oauth

Tags: c#, oauth, google-plus

Is there is anyway to post on google+ stream from C# winform application using OAuth ?..Please don't consider this as duplicate. I have seen so many posts in stackoverflow regarding the same.But,according to all ,google+ only providing read only API. But, I think things changed now. There is a way to do this. But how?..please throw some light

Answer (score 2):

As of today, there is still no "public" officially supported way to post on a Google+ stream using an API. (You can post using the +1 or Share buttons, but this isn't what you're looking for.)

Comment: bookmarking websites like socialexchangeit.com are doing automatic bookmarking in Google+. If there is no way to enter G+ stream,how they are managed to do this

Comment: Without seeing what the site is doing, I can't comment on how they're doing it. But I've clarified my reply that there are some private APIs that some selected partners are allowed to use. I don't know if they are using one of these APIs, if they have reverse engineered how the +1 button works, if they have hacked the +1 button, or if they have hacked the core UI itself.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to post using +1 button..How it is possible